# iPad image sizes

Tags: ios

I am creating an application for iPad, the images I have available from graphic designer are
really big, almost twice the size.

According to the graphic designer, the images were created keeping in mind iPad 3. 
So if I reduce my image size to half and use them, is it going to make any difference on iPad3?

Or there is no difference and it will be compatible in both.
I am new to iOS development and not sure about the image resizing in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these images in the app itself or the icon?

Answer (score 1):

You will have two versions of every image where one is double the size of the other and the operating system will decide which version to use. You just need to name the images correctly.

Images for ipad3 will have @2x within the name. Example

- image.png <--- non retina ipad
- image@2x.png <------ retina ipad (ipad3)

Here is a post explaining this more: [Preparing your iPhone App for Higher Resolutions](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/preparing-your-iphone-app-for-higher-resolutions/)